# Why SQL Server has stopped the execution?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a SQL server database and I connect to this with SQL Server management studio. When I execute a procedure if I close the client the database do not continue the execution. Why?

I assumed that the execution runs on the database and not in my local.

Thank you.

Comment: You are running the procedure query using client?

Comment: You really must provide more detailed information for people to be able to help you. Also, what do you mean by "not continue the execution"? The execution of the procedure, or do you mean the DB stops/hangs altogether?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will consider this observations for near posts. In this case I mean the procedure execution. Despite this Lucero has anwered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution runs on the database server alright. However, when the connection is closed along with the client (in this case the management studio is the client), this will have SQL Server abort and roll back the running transaction.

If you want to have something run independently of a client connection (at a schedule or triggered), you need to look into jobs for instance executed by [SQL Server Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Lucero. Now I understand what happened.